# Optimizing my method

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a utility method to perform mail merge-like functionality on a template file.  Since strings are immutable I'm unsure if I've written it properly - can somebody take a glance and give me feedback?

```
public static string LoadTemplateFile(string fileName, 
                                      NameValueCollection  mergeFields)
{
    string result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    if (mergeFields != null)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < mergeFields.Count; index++)
        {
            result = result.Replace(mergeFields.Keys[index], 
                                    mergeFields[index]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Optimize for memory usage or performance?

Comment: Efficiency.  I am using JaredPar's approach.

Comment: Do all your keys have the same, similar prefix? Split on that, then examine each substring, replace as required, then join. Requires multiple passes for nested keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to

1. Read a file from disk
2. Do a search / replace based on a provided name / value map

If that's the case then yes this will work just fine.

The only real feedback I have is that depending on the number of replacement name / value pairs, you're going to be creating a lot of temporary strings.  This is probably fine for small files but once you start loading relatively large files into your application you may see an appreciable difference.

A better approach would be to use a StringBuilder and do the Replace calls on that object.  It would reduce the unnecessary creation of temporary strings.

Comment: I never thought about using the Replace method of the StringBuilder.  When I use StringBuilders I'm usually am creating a string from scratch.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Not sure why a later answer with no code got marked, but glad you got it fixed!

Comment: @Adam - that's odd - I pulled up Jared's response and I didn't see yours.  Sorry!

Answer (score 10):

You'd probably do better to use a StringBuilder instead of a string.

```
public static string LoadTemplateFile(
    string fileName, NameValueCollection  mergeFields)
{    
    System.Text.StringBuilder result = new System.Text.StringBuilder(
        System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName));

    if (mergeFields != null)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < mergeFields.Count; index++)
        {
            result.Replace(mergeFields.Keys[index], 
                                    mergeFields[index]);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I can't see any string-concatenation in there, why use a StringBuilder?

Comment: Because the operations taking place a StringBuilder as generally faster, as it maintains its own internal buffer so you may or may not end up creating intermediate strings, whereas you're guaranteed to create them using string.Replace()

Comment: I'm guessing StringBuilder.Replace and String.Replace work differently: ie: String returning a string and StringBuilder modifying internally the string

Comment: It's not that its modifying it internally, its that its not imperatively doing the action, its recording your actions, then it does them when you call ToString, only it does this by avoiding temp allocations.

Answer (score 1):

use StringBuilder instead of string. that is my only advice, its way faster.